# Fullcalendar v4 eventColor not shown in monthView

Tags: javascript, c#, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

While switching to monthview from weekview(default), If there are events in selected  week view, then the `eventColor` works (i.e. Shows events with different color) while clicking the monthview but wont work if there are no data in weekview.

```
    $(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/BackOffice/Calendar/CalendarDetail',
            data: {
                eP: '@ViewBag.eP',
                supplierIds: '@customerIdList',
                appointmentType: '@appointmenttype',
                start: '@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")',
                end: '@DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(9).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")'
            },
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) { 
                var resources = [];
                debugger;
                for (var item = 0; item < data.length; ++item) {
                    if (data.indexOf(data[item].supplierId) < 1) {
                        resources.push({
                            id: data[item].supplierId,
                            title: data[item].supplierName,
                            eventColor: data[item].eventColor
                        });

                    }
                }
                calendarLoader(resources);
            },
            error: function(textstatus, jqxhr) {
                console.log(textstatus, jqxhr);

            }
        });

        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        @{
            var defaultView = "";
            var boldText = "";
            if (Model.IsSupplier)
            {
                defaultView = "resourceTimeGridDay";
                boldText = ".fc-resourceTimeGridDay-button";

            }
            else
            {
                defaultView = "timeGridWeek";
                boldText = ".fc-timeGridWeek-button";
            }
}
function calendarLoader(resources) {
                    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,
                        {
                            plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceDayGrid', 'resourceTimeGrid'],
                            defaultView: '@defaultView',
                            defaultDate: '@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")',
                            editable: true,
                            selectable: true,
                            locale: '@ViewBag.Language.ToString().ToLower()',
                            lazyFetching: true,
                            firstDay: (new Date().getDay()),
                            minTime: '09:00:00',
                            maxTime: '18:00:00',
                            header: {
                                center: "",
                                left: 'title',
                                right: 'resourceTimeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
                            },
                            buttonText: {
                                month: '@Resources.MvcGlobalResx.monthText',
                                week: '@Resources.MvcGlobalResx.weekText',
                                day: '@Resources.MvcGlobalResx.dayText'
                            },
                            filterResourcesWithEvents: true,
                            resources: resources,
                            hiddenDays: [0, 6],
                            events: {
                                url: '/BackOffice/Calendar/CalendarDetail?eP=' +
                                    '@ViewBag.eP' +
                                    '&&supplierIds=' +
                                    '@customerIdList' +
                                    '&&appointmentType=' +
                                    '@appointmenttype',

                                type: 'GET',
                            success: function (data) { 
                                var events = []; 
                                for (var item = 0; item < data.length; ++item) {
                                    events.push({
                                        id: data[item].Id,
                                        start: data[item].start,
                                        resourceId: data[item].supplierId,
                                        end: data[item].end,
                                        title: data[item].title,
                                        Phone: data[item].Phone,
                                        mobile: data[item].mobile,
                                        Id: data[item].Id,
                                        description: data[item].description,
                                        orderlines: data[item].orderlines,
                                        eP: data[item].eP,
                                        orderId: data[item].orderId
                                    });
                                }
                                return events;

                            }
                        },
                        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                            $('#calendar-modal .modal-title').text(calEvent.event.title);
                            $('#calendar-modal #mobile span').text(calEvent.event.extendedProps.mobile);
                            $('#calendar-modal #mobile').attr("href", "tel:" + calEvent.event.extendedProps.mobile);
                            if (calEvent.event.extendedProps.mobile == null) {
                                $('#calendar-modal #mobile').hide();
                            } else
                                $('#calendar-modal #mobile').show();
                            $('#calendar-modal #phone span').text(calEvent.event.extendedProps.Phone);
                            $('#calendar-modal #phone').attr("href", "tel:" + calEvent.event.extendedProps.Phone);
                            if (calEvent.event.extendedProps.Phone == null) {
                                $('#calendar-modal #phone').hide();
                            } else
                                $('#calendar-modal #phone').show();
                            if (calEvent.event.extendedProps.orderId === 0) {
                                $('#calendar-modal #orderep').hide();
                            } else
                                $('#calendar-modal #orderep').show();
                            if (calEvent.event.extendedProps.eP == "") {
                                $('#calendar-modal #manualAppointmentId')
                                    .attr('data-val', calEvent.event.extendedProps.Id);
                                $('#calendar-modal .modal-body h6').html(calEvent.event.extendedProps.description);
                                $('#calendar-modal #orderep').addClass("hidden");
                                $('#calendar-modal #manualAppointmentId').removeClass('hidden');

                            } else {
                                $('#calendar-modal .order-lines').html(calEvent.event.extendedProps.orderlines);
                                $('#calendar-modal #orderep').removeClass("hidden");
                                $('#calendar-modal #manualAppointmentId').addClass('hidden');
                                $('#calendar-modal .modal-body h6').html("");
                                var url = "/BackOffice/OrderDetails/Index?eP=" + calEvent.event.extendedProps.eP;
                                $('#calendar-modal #orderep').attr("href", url);

                            }
                            var mapurl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + calEvent.event.title;
                            $('#calendar-modal #map').attr("href", mapurl);
                            $('#calendar-modal').appendTo('body').modal('show');

                            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                        }
                    });
                calendar.render();
                $('@boldText').css('font-weight', 'bold');
                }
        var lan = "en";
        if ('@ViewBag.Language' != null)
            lan = '@ViewBag.Language.ToString().ToLower()';

}),
```

Comment: The solution to this is to have a separate resource feed, not dependent on which events are returned